# Having issues controlling the flow and user input of a telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

well i do have a couple issues first is the flow. i want the bot to go from start->contact_callback->get_password->log in-> index. after it gets to index i want it to recive user inputs from the keyboard and go to either balance or transfer then back to index. it is my first time making a bot so im not sure how to fix the issue. additionally i have trouble with accepting user input that is not from a keyboard like when retiriving amount and phone number in the transfer function. i know my code do be sh*t but i appreciate any help i can recive. i have attached the full code below.

```
   BOT_TOKEN = 'Hidden'
API_URL = 'Hidden'
from wsgiref import headers
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes, MessageHandler, filters
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, ConversationHandler, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler
import telegram
from typing import Dict
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from time import time, sleep
import time
from telegram.constants import ParseMode, ChatAction
import json
import re
from datetime import datetime
import requests

global global_phone_var
global global_acctok_var 
global global_name_var
global global_pass_var
global_pass_var = ""


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("at start func")
    await context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=update.effective_message.chat_id, action=ChatAction.TYPING)

    client_chat_obj = update.effective_message.chat
    client_user_id = client_chat_obj['id']
    
    if True:
            #ask to share phone number for first time
        
            custom_keyboard = [[KeyboardButton(text="Share Contact", request_contact=True)]]
        
        
            reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard)
        
            await update.message.reply_text(
            f"Hello {update.effective_user.first_name}! Please Share Your Phone Contact to register",
                reply_markup=reply_markup
            )
    else:
  
        # Suggest creating account
        await update.message.reply_text(
        "Please create a Prima Pay account using the mobile app. You can download it from: "
      "https://primapay.com"
        )

async def contact_callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
  await update.message.reply_text("at contact func")
  contact_obj = update.effective_message.contact
  client_chat_obj = update.effective_message.chat
  await update.message.reply_text("We got the Phone!", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
  global global_phone_var, global_name_var
  global_name_var = contact_obj.first_name
  global_phone_var = contact_obj.phone_number
  data = {
    'phone': contact_obj.phone_number
  }
  global_phone_var = contact_obj.phone_number
  response = requests.post(API_URL+'/user/get_registration_status',json=data)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    response_data = json.loads(response.text)
    error_state = response_data['error']
    if error_state == "true":
            await update.message.reply_text(response_data['error_msg'])
    else:
      await update.message.reply_text("Phone number found successfully!,please provide your password")
      #await get_password(update, context)

  else:
    await update.message.reply_text("Error contacting server from call back contact")

async def get_password(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    global global_pass_var
    password = update.message.text
    
    # Store the password in the global variable
    global_pass_var = password
    
    await update.message.reply_text("Password saved successfully!")
    await log_in(update,context)

async def log_in(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
  await update.message.reply_text("at log in func")
  global global_acctok_var
  await update.message.reply_text(global_pass_var)
  data = {
    "phone": global_phone_var,
    "login_password": global_pass_var,
}
  response = requests.post(API_URL+'/user/login',json=data)
  if response:
     await update.message.reply_text("response sent")
  if response.status_code == 200: 
     response_data = json.loads(response.text)
     global_acctok_var = response_data["data"]["user_data"]["access_token"]
     if global_acctok_var:
        await update.message.reply_text("yo yo we got the access tok")
        await update.message.reply_text(global_acctok_var)
        await index(update, context)
     else:
      await update.message.reply_text("Failed to get the access token")

async def index(update, context):
    global global_pass_var
    await update.message.reply_text("at index func")
    print(global_pass_var)
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([
        ['balance', 'transfer']
    ], resize_keyboard=True)
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Please select an option", 
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    await handle_reply(update,context)

async def handle_reply(update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text("at reply hand func")
    reply_text = update.message.text.lower()
    if reply_text == 'balance':
        await balance(update, context)
        await index(update, context)  # Call the index function after balance
    elif reply_text == 'transfer':
        await transfer(update, context)
        await index(update, context)  # Call the index function after transfer
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("Invalid option. Please select an option from the keyboard.")

async def balance(update, context):
 global global_acctok_var
 head = {
  "user_access_token": global_acctok_var, 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
 await update.message.reply_text("at balnce func")
 print(head)
 await update.message.reply_text(global_acctok_var)
 response = requests.post(API_URL+'/user/get_index',headers=head)
 await update.message.reply_text(response.status_code)
 if response.status_code == 200:
  await update.message.reply_text("request successful")
  response_data = json.loads(response.text)
  ledger_balance = response_data["data"]["ledger_data"]["balance"]
  await update.message.reply_text(ledger_balance)
  await index(update, context)
  
 elif response.status_code == 401:
    if response_data["error"] == "true":
     if response_data["error_msg"] == "token_is_invalid":
       await log_in(update,context)
    else:
     await update.message.reply_text("sorry a error has occured")
 else:
    await update.message.reply_text("unexpected error please restart the bot")

async def transfer(update, context, phone_number):

  amount = float(amount)

  phone_json = {"phone": phone_number}
  head = {
  "user_access_token": global_acctok_var, 
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
 
  ledger_response = requests.post(API_URL+'/user/get_ledger_id_by_phone',json=phone_json, headers=head)
  if ledger_response.status_code == 200:
    ledger_response_data = json.loads(ledger_response.text)
    ledger_id = ledger_response_data["data"]["ledger_id"]
    await update.message.reply_text(ledger_id)
    transfer_json = {
    "receiver_ledger_id": ledger_id,
    "amount": amount,
    "transaction_pin": "123456",
    "otp": "723740"
    }
    transfer_response = requests.post(API_URL+'/user/transfer_by_ledger_id',json = transfer_json, headers = head)
    if transfer_response.status_code == 200:
       transfer_data = json.loads(transfer_response.text)
       if transfer_data["data"]["transferred"]:
          await update.message.reply_text("congratulations the transfer is successful. your new balance is")
          await update.message.reply_text(transfer_data["data"]["updated_balance"])
       else:
         await update.message.reply_text("transfer is unsuccessful. your new balance is")
  await index(update, context)

async def text_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    incoming_text = update.message.text

    await update.message.reply_text(incoming_text +' is not implemented yet')
    await index(update, context)


app = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()
app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.CONTACT, contact_callback))
app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, get_password))

app.run_polling()`
```

i tried to add additional functions to handle responses but it isn't working